# Form submit prevention techniques not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel

What I'm trying to accomplish I've done several times before, but something seems to be different. This is my first project using laravel, and what I'm building is very basic. Still, the issue I would think is solely an HTML/JS issue, however I thought I should put that out there as I'm miffed.

**The behavior I'm trying to get**

User enters into input field, presses the enter key, and instead of submitting the form, the form is prevented from running (so that I can use ajax, however ajax is not yet part of this equation).

**What I've tried**

Here's the HTML.

```
<form action="test" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="text_input" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit_input" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

Here's some javascript I've tried.

This worked in past projects. However in this project, The alert happens, but the form is submitted. When I put the return false at the start, it prevents the form from submitting, however, then I can't run any code of course.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#submit_input').click(function() {
        alert();
        $('#text_input').val() = '';
        $('#text_input').focus();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've tried using preventDefault, that allows the alert to run, but does run any of the code after it.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert();
        $('#text_input').val() = '';
        $('#text_input').focus();
    });
});
```

**Solution I don't want**

I'm aware that I can get the inputs on button submit or enter key while focused on the field, and get this behavior without using the html form, and maybe I will, however, I want to know what's causing this not to work.

**JSFiddle**

I'm doing something wrong with my jsfiddle, so I'm not able to demonstrate with this. I haven't used a form on jsfiddle before, and I'm getting the error {"error": "Please use POST request"} but I don't know why, because I am specifying the post in the form.

http://jsfiddle.net/r50h0a44/

**Additional Information**

Doing this with Laravel 5, using WAMP, with jQuery 2.1 loaded, on Chrome, with no errors in my console. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `val()` in a wrong way. You should call it this way `$('#text_input').val('some text');`

Update:
You should use a second variant of your code (with `e.preventDefault()`)

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: If it solves the question, it's an answer.  Not every answer need be long.

Comment: That is an answer, as that's exactly what was causing the issue! I'm surprised Chrome Inspect Console doesn't show an error there. I guess it is technically valid, I suppose. I will use the second variant as well, as I understand that's best practice. Thank you for the quick and correct response.

Comment: @JaredSmith the problem was "that allows the alert to run, but does run any of the code after it." and that happened because the code was just wrong.

Comment: Odd that you didn't get a 'invalid left hand assignment' error. But I'm glad that your problem was solved. Please don't forget to accept the answer :)